# How to give inshort like (staking) animation with Recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, recyclerview-layout, pagersnaphelper

I am using Recycler view with SnapHelper and want animation like in bellow link but every other tutorial achieve this effect with viewpager, how to give this animation with Recycler view?

This is what i want to achieve [demo animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6jBP.gif).

Comment: Not the exact solution but you check this: https://www.journaldev.com/19336/android-nested-viewpager-vertical-viewpager

Comment: But i want to achieve this with Recycler view.